# Apply Type validation on Sharepoint list columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a dropdown list having list of all the columns present in a Sharepoint xyz list. Below is my code.

```
function getColumnname() 
{ 

var _fields = ''; 
var lEnum = fields.getEnumerator(); 
var fieldxList = document.getElementById('ddlxField');
$('#ddlxField').find('option:gt(0)').remove();


while(lEnum.moveNext()) 

{ 
    _fields = lEnum.get_current().get_title();
    var newListItem = document.createElement('OPTION'); 
    var box = _fields;
    newListItem.text = box;
    newListItem.value = box;
    fieldxList.add(newListItem);
    box.value = "";
 } 

 } 
<div>
 <select id="ddlxField"></select></div>
```

Now, what I want is to apply validation on this dropdown , so that user can choose only those column , whose type="Single line of text", if he chooses column name of some other type , it should prompt.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It should be achievable by adding the **onchange** event handler for your dropdownlist.

You will have to save the *field title* to *column type* mapping in an array/object, and refer it in your validation logic.

Comment: Yes , I will write the validation code on onchange event handler, but wanted to know  how to apply the validations . Do I need to use     SP.Field.get_fieldTypeKind function  ?

Comment: Basically , if I get the data type of selected column, then further logic for validation can be applied

Comment: You should be able to get it by querying *Field.TypeAsString* property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field.typeasstring.aspx)

Comment: hmmm... that is for C# and I want to do it by javascript. Anyways, thanks Manvir. I will try to find something in javascript.